# ICMP error message's data for IP datagram with < 64 bits payload?

Tags: ip, icmp

RFC792:

> The internet header plus the first 64 bits of the original
> datagram's data.  This data is used by the host to match the
> message to the appropriate process.  If a higher level protocol
> uses port numbers, they are assumed to be in the first 64 data
> bits of the original datagram's data.

RFC1812 4.3.2.3 Original Message Header:

> Historically, every ICMP error message has included the Internet
> header and at least the first 8 data bytes of the datagram that
> triggered the error.  This is no longer adequate, due to the use of
> IP-in-IP tunneling and other technologies.  Therefore, the ICMP
> datagram SHOULD contain as much of the original datagram as possible
> without the length of the ICMP datagram exceeding 576 bytes.  The
> returned IP header (and user data) MUST be identical to that which
> was received, except that the router is not required to undo any
> modifications to the IP header that are normally performed in
> forwarding that were performed before the error was detected (e.g.,
> decrementing the TTL, or updating options).  Note that the
> requirements of Section [4.3.3.5] supersede this requirement in some
> cases (i.e., for a Parameter Problem message, if the problem is in a
> modified field, the router must undo the modification).  See Section
> [4.3.3.5]).

None of them specified how to handle IP datagram with less than 8 bytes user data.

MAY the implementation discard ICMP error message or pad user data to 8 bytes?

Comment: As you say, the action isn't specified.  Different implementations may do different things.

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture that such a packet header would be padded with zeros (which is very much the standard procedure).

However, you'd be really hard pressed to create or even run across a practical packet with less than 8 bytes of IP payload: the smallest common protocol headers riding on top of IPv4 are from UDP and ICMP, each with a header size of 8 bytes.